# Solving sub-problems

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

When do I choose memoization over dynamic programming?
They both seem to possess identical time and space complexity.
What then would be the rules of thumb to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

[Memoization](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Memoization) is a technique used in dynamic programming, not a separate entity.  Time/space complexity depends on the algorithm and implementation.

[Dynamic programming](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Dynamic_Programming), in general, is a strategy of recognizing common sub-tasks in a job.  Instead of executing the sub-tasks multiple times, you use system resources other than execution cycles to capture the execution results for later use.

Typically, this is a simple matter of storing computation results to avoid duplication of computational effort.  In most cases, this involves storing functional results, indexed by the parameter values.  This is memoization.

In more detail ...

DP comes in two basic flavours: top-down and bottom-up.  The bottom-up method starts with the base case and works up to the requested result.  This is often implemented with a simple iteration loop and an array to store intermediate results.

The top-down method is memoization.  This breaks the original request into smaller problems, and recurs on each of those.  As it solves each sub-problem, it stores the result to be used by other branches needing the same result.